# Spark query planner generates different queries randomly

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark job which gets data from a table in SQL Server and generates 
a where clause for predicates to push down in `jdbc` function to a destination table which is in MySQL. I am using Spark 2.3 in Cloudera.

Predicate code:

```
.jdbc(s"<dest_db_url>", config.destTable,predicate, destOptions)
```

The where clause that I pass to `predicate` array is like this

```
Array(
"(composite_primary_key1='ABCD' AND composite_primary_key2='123') OR 
(composite_primary_key1='EFGH' AND composite_primary_key2='456')",
"(composite_primary_key1='WXYZ' AND composite_primary_key2='342') OR
 (composite_primary_key1='QWYS' AND composite_primary_key2='664')"
)
```

The code snippet to generate above `predicate` is

```
val predicates = sourceData
.map(row => s"(composite_primary_key1='${row.composite_primary_key1}' AND composite_primary_key2='${row.composite_primary_key2}')")
.reduce(_+" OR "+_)
```

The query that gets pushed down to MySQL is like this

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE 
(composite_primary_key1 IS NOT NULL AND composite_primary_key2 IS NOT NULL) AND 
((composite_primary_key1='ABCD' AND composite_primary_key2='123') OR 
(composite_primary_key1='EFGH' AND composite_primary_key2='456'))
```

The **(composite_primary_key1 IS NOT NULL AND composite_primary_key2 IS NOT NULL)** condition gets prepended to the actual predicate. Because of which the query scans a lot more rows than required in MySQL making the query inefficient.

This behavior is quite random. Sometimes spark generates a proper query like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE  
((composite_primary_key1='ABCD' AND composite_primary_key2='123') OR 
(composite_primary_key1='EFGH' AND composite_primary_key2='456'))
```

Without the NULL checks. Unable to figure out this random behaviour.

Comment: Can you provide some code snippet where you are generating this logic?

Comment: I have added the code snippet